# Store version in Java-Git projects

Tags: java, git, version, versioning

What is the best way to store the version of my application?

I use [Git tagging](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Tagging) to store a [semantic version number](http://semver.org/) in the Git repository. But I also want to print out the version number to the user of the program (f.ex. when a user calls `./myprogram --version`). So I also had to manually change a String constant in my Java source code for every new version.

Is there a smarter way to keep the version numbers in the Git repository and the source code in sync?

Comment: Found a decent answer on programmers stack exchange:

http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/141973/how-do-you-achieve-a-numeric-versioning-scheme-with-git

Comment: If you use maven you can use the [git-commit-id-plugin](https://github.com/ktoso/maven-git-commit-id-plugin). If you don't... well, there surely is a plugin for whatever build tool you're using. Write the version number to a file that is read by your program.

Comment: @musiKk: Cool tip, I didn't have the idea to use the build tool for this task. For `sbt` I found now [sbt-release](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-release). You should write it as answer, so I can accept this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In our project we use the [git-commit-id-plugin](https://github.com/ktoso/maven-git-commit-id-plugin) for maven. You can generate something that can be read at runtime by your program, e.g., a Java class that contains static fields or a properties file that is read.

If you don't use maven, there surely is a plugin for your build tool or, at the very least, the possibility to somehow call `git describe` (as suggested by others).

Answer (score 2):

You can get the current tag from git using

```
git describe [--abbrev=0] > localFileForTag
```

If you put that line into a script and run that script during the build process, you can store the current tag in a local file. Your program just has to read and print the file content.